# How can I make a Facebook 'like' button for an iframe Appication?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, fbml

I'm trying to make a like button for my iframe facebook app.

With an FBML application, clicking the like button would put "Pete likes AppName (Application)." on your wall.

For my iframe app I'm using the following FBML:

```
<fb:like href="http://apps.facebook.com/appname/"></fb:like>
```

However Facebook changes the hyperlink to the iframe's domain:
http://mydomain.com/app/

Which puts the following on my wall: "Pete likes App Name on mydomain.com" and the link follows through to http://mydomain.com/app/

How can I make a like button which works the same as an FBML application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application's profile is what is "like-able".

i.e., this URL: `http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=YOUR_APP_ID`

Comment: Thanks, however I'm getting an error (rendered when you click the 'like' button):
"The page at http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=MY_APP_ID could not be reached."

Might this be caused by the face my app is not yet in the app directory?

Comment: Is your app in sandbox mode?  Are you logged in to Facebook?

Comment: No and yes respectively. The application is now listed in the Application directory, and it still doesn't work!

Comment: Apparently the app needs to be listed in the app directory AND it takes a few days to start working.